# Extend matomo/piwik device detector class to add new client parser (namespace issue)

Tags: php, class, namespaces, extends, matomo

I am trying to add a custom user agent for parsing a custom mobile application user agent along with the existing parsers. I tried following the issue over here: https://github.com/matomo-org/device-detector/issues/5931 but could not do it properly.

**Directory Structure**

```
UAParserService
|
|_ composer.json
|_ Vendor
|_ index.php
|_ custom_apps.yml
|_ CustomAppParser.php
|_ DeviceDetector.php
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use DeviceDetector\DeviceDetector;
use DeviceDetector\Parser\Client\CustomAppParser;

$userAgent = "MyApp/1.0.0 (Linux; Android 9; ONEPLUS A6010)"; // Android App

$dd = new DeviceDetector($userAgent);
$parser = new CustomAppParser();
$dd -> addClientParser($parser);
$dd -> parse();

// Check if user agent is a bot
$isBot = $dd -> isBot();

if($isBot) {
    echo json_encode(["is_bot" => $isBot]);
}
else {
    $clientInfo = $dd->getClient();
    $osInfo = $dd->getOs();
    $device = $dd->getDeviceName();
    $brand = $dd->getBrandName();
    $model = $dd->getModel();

    echo json_encode([
        "is_bot" => $isBot,
        "client_info" => $clientInfo,
        "os_info" => $osInfo,
        "device_type" => $device,
        "device_brand" => $brand,
        "device_model" => $model,
    ], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

**DeviceDetector.php**

```
<?php


    namespace UAParserService\DeviceDetector;
    
    use function array_pop;
    use function array_unshift;
    
    class DeviceDetector extends \DeviceDetector\DeviceDetector
    {
        public function addClientParser($parser){
            parent::addClientParser($parser);
    
            $item = array_pop($this -> clientParsers);
            array_unshift($this -> clientParsers, $item);
        }
    }
```

**CustomAppParser.php**

```
<?php


namespace DeviceDetector\Parser\Client;


class CustomAppParser extends ClientParserAbstract
{
    protected $fixtureFile = "custom_apps.yml";
    protected $parserName  = "mobile app";

    protected function getRegexesDirectory()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__);
    }
}
```

**composer.json**

```
{
  "require": {
    "piwik/device-detector": "3.11.7",
    "ext-json": "*"
  }
}
```

I am extremely unfriendly with namespaces so I might be doing it totally wrong.

I also do get some errors:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DeviceDetector\Parser\Client\FurryAppParser' not found in F:\web projects\project1\UAParserService\index.php on line 17
>
> ( ! ) Error: Class 'DeviceDetector\Parser\Client\CustomAppParser' not found in F:\web projects\project1\UAParserService\index.php on line 17

Comment: Since you seem to be using composer (which uses PSR-4 auto loading), I would recommend that you look through the [PSR-4 auto loading standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and [composers[manual about PSR-4 auto loading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4). The files simply needs to be placed (and named) correctly and you need to let composer know where to find what namespace. The links goes though that.

Comment: If its about correctly letting composer know where to find the namespaces, then to achieve that, leaving the composer part is the implementation correct?

Comment: You're code is not compatible with PSR-4. The file names need to be the same as the class names. So the class `class Foo {}` should be stored in `Foo.php` (with the same casing). You also need to edit composer.json to define where the root folder for the `DeviceDetector` namespace should be. If you read the links i posted, they will give you some examples and a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have corrected the file and class names. Now does Root folder of device detector mean the vendor folder?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am sorry but I was unable to properly edit the composer.json. I tried by adding: `"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "DeviceDetector\\": "vendor/piwik/device-detector/"
    }
  }` which actually did nothing. One more question will I need to call any of this classes from index anymore if composer.json editing is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should consider to put your own classes into dedicated folder, like `src`.

After that you can add

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "UAParserService\\": "src/"
    }
  }
```

to your `composer.json` and update autoloader with `composer dump-autoload` command.

At this point you will have setup for use of your namespace.

**Things to note**:

- all your classes in `src` folder must start its namespace with `UAParserService\`
- Filename must match classname (case sensitive)
- Folder structure must match namespace's elements (case sensitive)
- `UAParserService` element will be stripped while searching folders for your class

For example, if `DeviceDetector` class have `namespace UAParserService\DeviceDetector;` it must be placed into `scr/DeviceDetector/DeviceDetector.php` file. The same goes for `CustomAppParser` class.

Also, if you want to use **your own** `DeviceDetector` in `index.php` you should update `use` statement to
`use UAParserService\DeviceDetector\DeviceDetector;`

**Side note**: please don't use spaces around `->` operator for methods calls ;). At least either use it everywhere, either don't use it at all...

**P.S.**: please consider to rename your question to reflect real issue it solves ;). I mean we are solving here namespace issue, not extending issue.